# how to determine if gulp watch is running

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I run gulp on server in background running

```
gulp &
```

but sometimes it fail down. So mi question is: Is there some command for gulp to ask if is running. Something like

```
gulp status
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to be alerted when it stops?  Are you trying to restart it when it stops automatically?

Comment: `ps aux | grep gulp` should list gulp processes running

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special in gulp to limit running multiple processes or alert you to an already running gulp process.

Use regular Unix techniques to check if a process is running.  Use a supervisor like supervisord or runit to automatically restart processes.

```
#the program pidof will set the variable $? to either
#1 or 0 in bash depending on if it finds a process
#with that name.  It will also print out all the matching
#process IDs to the command line
pidof gulp
echo $?  #1 if there is no process called gulp
         #0 if there is a process called gulp
if pidof gulp; then 
   echo 'gulp is alive';
else
   echo 'we need some support over here!'
   ./node_modules/.bin/gulp watch &
   sleep 3
fi
```